# How to use jQuery to remove multiple texts inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have search results and they are concatenated with multiple words at the beginning of the sentence.

```
<div itemprop="articleSection" class="entry-summary">
WHAT WE DOSource Integrate Support Manage Transform A metre-wide “lazy river” of cobblestones meanders through the clay-paved plaza fronting Australia’s newest international-standard swim centre.
</div>
```

I want to remove the words ***"WHAT WE DOSource Integrate Support Manage Transform"*** from the beginning of ***EACH*** `class="entry-summary"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this jQuery

**jQuery**

```
$('.entry-summary').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('WHAT WE DOSource Integrate Support Manage Transform', '')); 
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/6gk3ztju/12/)**

Comment: Good answer Luis.  Hopefully anyone reading this knows to change your .removetext selector to match whatever selector they have.  In the case of the OP ".removetext" would be changed to ".entry-summary"

Comment: @kasdega thanks...i edit my answer  base on the class of the OP

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`.text`**](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method to change the text:

```
$('.entry-summary').text(function(index, value) {
  return value.replace(
    /^\s*WHAT WE DOSource Integrate Support Manage Transform/,
    ''
  );
});
```

Comment: This is the answer I would use too.

Answer (score 0):

You could just split it:

```
$('.entry-summary:contains("Transform ")').text(function(_, txt){
    return txt.split('Transform ')[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use str_replace function.

```
var str = $(".entry-summary").html(); 
var res = str.replace("WHAT WE DOSource Integrate Support Manage Transform", "");
$(".entry-summary").html(res);
```